# WSUS showing required updates, but server says up to date?

Tags: wsus

I have multiple servers that are showing 10-20 updates required in the WSUS console.

The server says that it is up to date.  I have verified that the update is approved and shows as install status, but the server still doesn't download it?

I have downloaded the suspect updates from the Windows Update site, and tried installing them, and they all install and show the server needed them.

After running wuauclt /reportnow the WSUS server shows those updates as installed and not needed.

Does anyone have any idea why the server can get these updates from the WSUS server?  is it a setting I have wrong?  Nothing has changed in the configuration in quite some time.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked that the WSUS server has successfully downloaded the updates in question?

Comment: Yes when I add the downloaded column to the all updates section it shows all as downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSUS is completely broken with Windows 10. I have had nothing but problems and tried rebuilding the server a few times and ended up having the same problems. I even tried building a server 2019 with WSUS and had the same problems. I would recommend using group policy to control windows 10 updates and allowing the systems to go directly out to Microsoft to get the updates.

The GPO settings are located at: Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update > Windows Update for Business

Comment: I concur with the observation of it being broken.

Comment: I am running this on 2012 servers and trying to update 2008 -2019 servers, not desktop clients.  We do use GPO but do not want to go out to Microsoft to get the updates as we can't test them in our dev environment before putting them in production.

Comment: Just as a data point, we have a Windows 2016 WSUS server and a mix of Windows 7 and Windows 10 clients and everything is working for us.